# How to track mouse over SWT composite made from sub controls?

Tags: java, swt

I have a created my own control:

[image: screenshot of my composite]

I want to track the mouse and added a `MouseTrackListener`. Unfortunately `MouseEnter` and `MouseLeave` events are also generated, when the mouse moves over the parts of my composite (that is the label and the button).

[image]

```
[Mouse enter] - mouse enters the empty space
[Mouse hover] - mouse is over the empty space
[Mouse exit]  - mouse moved over label
[Mouse enter] - mouse leaves label and enters empty space
[Mouse hover] - mouse over empty space
[Mouse exit]  - mouse leaves composite
```

How can I track the composite as one complete thing instead of sub parts?

```
public class MyComposite extends Composite {
    public MyComposite(final Composite parent, final int style) {
        super(parent, style);

        final Label lbl = new Label(this, SWT.NONE);
        lbl.setBounds(10, 10, 78, 15);
        lbl.setText("My Composite");

        final Button btn = new Button(this, SWT.NONE);
        btn.setBounds(190, 29, 75, 25);
        btn.setText("Ok");

        pack();
    }

    public static void main(final String[] args) {
        final Shell shell = new Shell(Display.getDefault());
        shell.setText("Testcase");
        shell.setLayout(new FillLayout());

        final MyComposite comp = new MyComposite(shell, SWT.NONE);
        comp.addMouseTrackListener(new MouseTrackListener() {
            @Override
            public void mouseHover(final MouseEvent e) {
                System.out.println("[Mouse hover]");
            }

            @Override
            public void mouseExit(final MouseEvent e) {
                System.out.println("[Mouse exit]");
            }

            @Override
            public void mouseEnter(final MouseEvent e) {
                System.out.println("[Mouse enter]");
            }
        });

        shell.open();
        while (!shell.isDisposed()) {
            if (!display.readAndDispatch())
                display.sleep();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5):

If you want to get only mouse move events you can add a untyped event to `Composite`. It should be something like

```
final Composite comp = new Composite(shell, org.eclipse.swt.SWT.NONE);
comp.addListener(SWT.MouseMove, new Listener() {
    public void handleEvent(Event event) {
        System.out.println("hit");
    }
});
```

If you add the same Listener instance to all the children of `MyComposite` then you can capture all the mouse move events.

Alternately you can use `Display.addFilter` to catch all the mouse events and filter if the ones that happen on your `Composite` instance or any of its children.

A third option is to use `Composite.setCapture` to get all mouse events when mouse enters the `Composite` area and stop capturing when it leaves.

Out of these I think the first option is probably the best performant.

Comment: When catching `MouseMove` events, how can I extract `MouseEnter` and `MouseExit` events?

Comment: The problem with `setCapture` is, that `mouseExit()` won't be triggered any longer, so I have to invent another mechanism to call `setCapture(false)`.

Comment: I thought you did not want the Enter & Exit events.

Comment: I only want to get rid of the "subcomponents" enter and exit events.

Comment: Then you can add the MouseEnter & Exit listeners to only your Composite

Comment: @GorkemErcan That's what the OP is doing. Look at the code the OP provided.

Comment: @Baz No it is not the same thing. That code is using MouseTrackListener. MouseTrackListener listens to all three events (MouseMove, MouseEnter,MouseExit), on the components that it was added to. What I am suggesting is to add the same MouseMove listener to Composite and its children and MouseEnter and MouseExit to only Composite. This is a bit more manageable.

Comment: @Baz Give it a try and let me know :)