# Implementing detection of mousing on/off an object in a Java card game

Tags: java, swing, mouseevent, mouselistener

I am modifying an [**open source Java card game**](https://code.google.com/p/soljava/source/browse/trunk/soljava/src/kabalpackage/?r=3). Basically, I want to detect when a user mouses over, and mouses off, a specific card. This should be pretty simple to implement with mouseExit/mouseEntered functions of a MouseListener, however I am having trouble.

In the [**GameArea.java**](https://code.google.com/p/soljava/source/browse/trunk/soljava/src/kabalpackage/GameArea.java?r=3) file, a series of stacks (DealtCardStack objects) are initialised and assigned a mouse handler (**line 175+**). The mouse functions for this handler contain pretty much all the code used for moving and playing cards between the main stacks, it can be found from **line 479** onwards. I added a mouseExited/Entered function to this handler, but it only works for entering/exiting the stack. This sort of works for some cases, but there are a few cases were it is not accurate enough and I need to detect it down to specific cards within stacks, so it can detect leaving and entering cards within the same stack.

I tried creating a new mouse listener and attaching it to each card as it's created (cards are created in the [**Deck class**](https://code.google.com/p/soljava/source/browse/trunk/soljava/src/kabalpackage/Deck.java?r=3), **line 75**). When I created a mouse listener it forced me to override mouseMove, Click etc., so I left those blank and just added some code to mouseEnter and mouseExit (just a print for testing purposes). I tested the program and the prints appeared as I entered/left a card exactly how I wanted, however I could no longer click or drag, or interact with the cards in anyway, essentially the functionality of the game (established in GameArea) was removed. Why is this? Does java only support one mouse handler in a program at a time? I didn't think this was the case as the GameArea seems to have two handlers (one for handling events on the deck in the corner). I thought perhaps the new mouse handler assigned to each card overridden all the functionality specified in GameArea, but I'm confused as that mouse handler is assigned to dealtCards, which is an array of DealtCardStacks, and this new handler was assigned to individual cards.

So, does anyone know why I am having trouble assigning these mouse handlers to the various objects in the program? Or is there a better/easier solution for achieving what I want to do?

I found [**this question**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16543662/how-to-track-mouse-over-swt-composite-made-from-sub-controls) which seems very relevant to my problem, however I tried implementing a MouseTrackListener and the type was not read, and could not be imported from anywhere.

I've tried to make the question as clear as possible, there is a lot of code in the project but I think you will only need to read the linked classes, at the lines specified in bold. If anything is not clear please let me know.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

i'm not sure, but if you add an mouseListener to the Deck, you DONT add the mouseMotionListener...   is it intenionally? shouldn't it also have added the mouseMotionListener so you can receive drags  drops?

but i think it's correct to add the listener to each of the cards in your Deck.

Comment: Sorry I don't get what you mean. None of the linked code is mine so I'm not too sure about all of it. I've solved my problem now, posting an answer shortly.

Answer (score 0):

So I MOSTLY solved it. I've got code for detecting moving onto a card in the mouseMove function, this uses an over_card and new_over_card variable to detect changes so it will detect entering and exiting cards within the same stack. I then just use a mouseExit on the stack objects to detect leaving a stack altogether. These combine to pretty much cover moving into and out of all the cards.